# My Splash Screen Doent Seen If I Add Sleep Method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

In my adnroid project i add an splash screen and i'm displaying it for 5 sec and i wanna start up my MainMenu activity but splash screen doesn't show up in the screen it waits me 9 sec and go directly my MainMenu layout and if i discart that part of code it displays my Splash i couldn't find what is wrong with my code so here it is my Splash class

```
    public class Splash extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {

                        Intent startIntent;
                        startIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINMENU");
                        startActivity(startIntent);

                }
            }
        };
        timer.run();

    }
}
```

and this is my MainMenu class

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {

private static ArrayList<ArrayList> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
TextView tx;
String temp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    temp = "";
            try {
                result = MethodInfoGetter.methodRequest("BaskanOzgecmisGetir", "", "");
                Log.i("MainMenu","Result gelis vakti");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*if(result.isEmpty())
            {
                tx.setText("Result is emty");
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < result.get(i).size() ; j++ )
                    {
                    temp += result.get(i).get(j) + " \n";

                    }   
                }
            }
            tx.setText(temp);*/

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

and if you guys needed here is my android manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >"
    <activity
        android:name="com.BLKBelediye.balikesirbelediye.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINMENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.BLKBelediye.balikesirbelediye.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the thread using method start() and not run() so that the thread runs asynchronously.

Replace timer.run() by timer.start()

timer.run() call is making your current UI thread sleep for 5 seconds.

Comment: Welcome! Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use CountDownTimer

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Timer_Countdown timer_Countdown = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    timer_Countdown = new Timer_Countdown(5000, 1000);
    timer_Countdown.start();
}

class Timer_Countdown extends CountDownTimer
{
    public Timer_Countdown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        timer_Countdown.cancel();
         Intent startIntent;
         startIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAINMENU");
         startActivity(startIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice i will do for my other activity in my project